# redux-toolkit -- Type error: "unit" is read-only

Tags: react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am using react-redux and redux-toolkit for this project. I want to add item to the cart. If there is already a same item in cart, just increment the unit. The error occurs at the slice, so I will just show the slice here.

```js
const CartListSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'cartItem',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
      addToCart: (state, action) => {
        let alreadyExist = false;
// get a copy of it to avoid mutating the state
        let copyState = current(state.cartItem).slice();
        // loop throught the cart to check if that item is already exist in the cart
        copyState.map(item => {
              if (item.cartItem._id === action.payload._id) {
                alreadyExist = true;
                item.unit += 1  // <--- Error occurs here
              }
            })
        
// If the item is not exist in the cart, put it in the cart and along with its unit
        if (alreadyExist === false) {
          state.cartItem.push({
            cartItem: action.payload, 
            unit: 1
          });
        }
      },
    }
});
```

I get a type error telling me that `unit` is read-only.
How can I update the "unit" variable so that it increments whenever it is supposed to.

Comment: Can you show us `initialState`? Also, can you give us a code sample on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)?

Comment: oh sure, ```const initialState = {
    cartItem: [],

}```

Comment: Have you tried to get rid of `copyState` and just use `state.cartItem` in your `addToCart` reducer function?

Comment: Without `current`. Just remove `current`, and leave the rest and let us know if it's working

Comment: Oh thanks, after removing copyState, it works.  Thanks a lot for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React Toolkit's `createSlice`, you can modify the `state` directly and even should do so. So don't create a copy, just modify it.
In fact, this error might in some way stem from making that copy with `current`.

[See the "Writing Reducers with Immer" documentation page on this](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers)

Meanwhile, a suggestion:

```js
const CartListSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'cartItem',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
      addToCart: (state, action) => {
        const existingItem = state.find(item => item.cartItem._id === action.payload._id)
        if (existingItem) {
          item.unit += 1
        } else {
          state.push({
            cartItem: action.payload, 
            unit: 1
          });
        }
      },
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried your code and get "item" is undefined, I think you have forgotten to wrap it inside this code: ```current(state.cartItem).map(item => {}``` By the way, no luck, the code does not work, but thanks for your helping

Comment: I use back my code but this time I do not use copyState. It works after removing the copyState, thanks for helping me.

Comment: I corrected my answer, it needs to be `.find(item -> item....` instead of `.find(item...`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need line:

```
let copyState = current(state.cartItem).slice();
```

Instead of `copyState`, just use `state.cartItem.map`

As @phry said, you should mutate `state` directly, because redux-toolkit is using immerJS in the background which takes care of mutations.

Comment: yea, and ````current(state.cartItem) is not needed```, thanks a lot for your help